# integral evaluation of an exponential

Tags: fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, exponential-function

let be the function

$$ e^{-a|x|^{b}} $$

with $ a,b $ positive numbers bigger than zero

then how could i evaluate this 2 integrals ?

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dxe^{-a|x|^{b}}e^{cx}$$

here 'c' can be either positive or negative or even pure complex (Fourier transform)

also how i would evaluate the Fourier cosine trasnform

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}dxe^{-a|x|^{b}}cos(cx)$$

thanks in advance if possible give a hinto of course i know tht i could expand the function in powers of $ |x| $ but if possible i would like a closed answer thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really interested in finding a closed form formula, you can have it in terms of the [Fox $H$-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function). However, I am adopting the [following convention (see section 3 & 5)](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KZWIzZjIxZGQtN2M4NC00N2MzLTk1YmQtM2M2NmVhYmE4NzA5/edit?hl=en_US) of the $H$-function which follows from the Mellin-Barnes integrals.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a|x|^{b}}e^{cx} dx= \frac{1}{ac}H^{1,1}_{1,1} \left[ \frac{c}{a^b} \left| \begin{matrix} ( 1 , \frac{1}{b} ) \\ ( 1 , 1 )  \end{matrix} \right. \right] -\frac{1}{ac}H^{1,1}_{1,1} \left[ \frac{-c}{a^b} \left| \begin{matrix} ( 1 , \frac{1}{b} ) \\ ( 1 , 1 )  \end{matrix} \right. \right] \,.$$

Offcourse there are existence conditions for the above formula. The above formula can be simplified in terms of less general functions depending on $b$. Just try it for some special values of $b$.

Comment: ok thank you D ::D :D :D ,also what would happen if we take the limit $ \epsilon \to 0 $ with $ a= \epsilon $ and $ b= 1+\epsilon $