# How are Fox-H functions useful in math?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, special-functions

The [Fox H-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function), as far as I know, is the most general families of functions - encompassing an even larger family of functions than the already very general [Meijer G-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function). While I've known about these functions for a while, I've never seen a good use of them - are they just generalizations for generalizations sake? Is there ever a time when the use of these functions has given insight into a problem that other assumptions (smooth, continuous, etc.) could not? What fields are they most used in?

Comment: It is usually very rare that general results can be proven using them but it does happen.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for examples where this is the case.

Comment: Apparently there are applications in [fractional diffusion](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704003826)

Comment: And finally here is [a book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=m8V8sYlb4UMC&pg=PA251&lpg=PA251&dq=applications+of+fox+h-function&source=bl&ots=DKEsgN7HTc&sig=W2OPgTnICx3sm0YYz9HVQhLpOW4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lekyVJyWINDmaNPZgKgI&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=applications%20of%20fox%20h-function&f=false) discussing the H-Function in depth.

Comment: There are functions more general than Fox's H-function. The H-function has uses in fluids, special functions, Mellin transforms, fractional calculus, etc.. There are cases where it is better to use the H-function, rather than the G-function, due to the structure of the poles in the contour. The pole location is what makes the A, A*, and I-functions arise.

Comment: As pointed out in kjetil b halvorsen's answer, mathematical statistics is one area. I'm personally using the Meijer G-Function to find a generalization of a collection of probability density functions.

Answer (score 11):

[Fox–Wright function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) or even the [Fox H-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function) are very useful on dealing the infinte series expressions whose its coefficient involves for example the gamma functions of linear expressions in the index $n$.

For example:

[Definite Integral of $e^{ax+bx^c}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204181/definite-integral-of-eaxbxc/465862#465862)

[Definite integration of a high order exponential function mixed with rational function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390211/definite-integration-of-a-high-order-exponential-function-mixed-with-rational-fu/458003#458003)

[Can this series be expressed as a Hyper Geometric function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087184/can-this-series-be-expressed-as-a-hyper-geometric-function/1200801#1200801)

We can't say that the [Fox H-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function) is the most general families of functions, since in fact there are no functions really in the most general families.

There are still some situations where [Fox–Wright function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) or even the [Fox H-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_H-function) are still not enough to use, for example in [Integral $\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{1+2^x+3^x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612879/integral-int-1-infty-fracdx12x3x/741742#741742).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any function academically accepted whose special case is the Fox h function, like maybe the [Kampé de Fériet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kampé_de_Fériet_function) function?

Answer (score 8):

This link http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a252517.pdf   is a PhD-thesis using H-function in the study of statistical distributions.  There are other papers with applications in this area, such as
The Distribution of Products, Quotients and Powers of Independent H-Function Variates
by  Bradley D. Carter and Melvin D. Springer
SIAM J. Appl. Math., 33(4), 542–558. (17 pages)

Read More: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0133036

Search in google scholar will give you more papers in this area.

Read More: http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0133036