# Can this series be expressed as a Hyper Geometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am trying find a Hyper Geometric function representation of the following series.
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^k}{k!}\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{b+k}{c}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}$$
but the closest function I have found is [Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) which is described in terms of [Pochhammer Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html)
which requires solving
$$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{b+k}{c}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} = \frac{\frac{\Gamma \left(u + k \right)}{\Gamma \left(u\right)}}{\frac{\Gamma \left(v + k\right)}{\Gamma \left(v\right)}}$$ for $u$ and $v$,
or [Confluent Hypergeometric Limit Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricLimitFunction.html) which is defined using only one Pochhammer symbol and requires solving
$$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{b+k}{c}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{b}{c}\right)} = \frac{\Gamma \left(u \right)}{\Gamma \left(u + k\right)}$$ for $u$ and I think is overdetermined and in-consistent, so just comparing parameters does not work.

I am wondering if there is a generalisation of these functions which would work for this series or if I am mistaken and these equations are solvable. Maybe it's a dumb thing to ask. Maybe there is a simple answer that I couldn't see. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is indeed *a* closed form $($not necessarily the best$)$, which can be deduced by letting $c=1,2,3,4,$ $5,\ldots$ and using a CAS to solve each such individual case, then generalize the results.

Comment: @Lucian, Can u please be more specific which one of the two cases are u referring to ? Also what does CAS stand for ?

Comment: You have to get fancy because the ratio of successive coefficients is not a polynomial in k.  What is your purpose?  The coefficients and series can be transformed and closed; with the possibility of an integral being left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function,

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{a^k}{k!}\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{b+k}{c}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{b}{c}\right)}=~_1\Psi_1\left[\begin{matrix}\left(\dfrac{b}{c},\dfrac{1}{c}\right)\\\left(\dfrac{b}{c},0\right)\end{matrix};a\right]$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{a^k}{k!}\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{b+k}{c}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\dfrac{b}{c}\right)}= \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)}~_1\Psi_0\left[\begin{matrix}\left(\frac{b}{c},\frac{1}{c}\right)\\-\end{matrix};a\right]$