# Integral form(s) of a general tetration/power tower integral solution: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(pn+q)^{rn+s}Γ(An+B,Cn+D)}{Γ(an+b,cn+d)}$

Tags: integration, gamma-function, tetration, summation-method, power-towers

In many [tetration/power tower](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) integrals, one sees a general form of the following. Let this new function be notation used to show the connection between the general result and special cases using types of [Incomplete Gamma functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Regularized_Gamma_functions_and_Poisson_random_variables).

The goal is to find an integral representation of the general case or a special case.

If this is not possible, then maybe a special case of it has an integral representation. Note there are ways to put the summand into other functions, but this way is simple. Please note that I will use a made up general “T” function to show how each integral below it is a special case of the following:

$$T_{p,q}^{r,s}\left(_{\ \ a,b,c,d}^{A,B,C,D}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(pn+q)^{rn+s}Γ(An+B,Cn+D)}{Γ(an+b,cn+d)}$$

Here is motivation that integral representations are possible. Note that I will use the [primitive](https://socratic.org/questions/is-there-a-difference-between-an-integral-and-a-primitive-function) for simplicity:

$$\int (cx)^{ax^b}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-a)^n Q(n+1,-(bn+1)\ln(cx))}{c^{bn+1}(bn+1)^{n+1}}= \frac{1}{-ac^{b-1}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ (-ac^bbn-ac^b)^{n+1}Γ(n+1,-bn\ln(cx)-\ln(cx))}{Γ(n+1,0)} =  -\frac{1}{ac^{b-1}}  T_{-abc^b,-ac^b}^{1,1}\left(_{\ \ 1,1,0,0}^{1,1,-b\ln(cx),-\ln(cx)}\right) $$

$$\int a^{ta^t}dt=t+\frac{1}{\ln(a)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^n Q(n+1,-nt\,\ln(a))}{n^{n+1}}= t-\frac{1}{\ln(a)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-n)^{-n-1} Γ(n+1,-nt\,\ln(a))}{Γ(n+1,0)} =t-\frac{1}{\ln(a)} T_{-1,0}^{-1,-1}\left(_{\ \ 1,1,0,0}^{1,1,-t\,\ln(a),0}\right) $$

$$\int \frac{dx}{xe^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{Γ(n+1,-nx)}{n^{n+1}}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty n^{-n-1} Γ(n+1,-nx)= T_{1,0}^{-1,-1}\left(_{0,1,0,0}^{1,1,-x,0}\right) $$

$$\int \text W(\ln(x))dx=\text W(\ln(x))(x-1)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n Q(n+1,-n\,\text W(\ln(x))}{n^{n+1}}= \text W(\ln(x))(x-1) -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-n)^{-n-1}Γ(n+1,-n\,\text W(\ln(x))}{Γ(n+1)} = T_{-1,0}^{-1,-1}\left(_{1,1,0,0}^{1,1, -\,\text W(\ln(x)),0}\right) $$

Miscellaneous sums of interest. [Subfactorial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement):
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{!n}=e\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{Γ(n+2,-1)}=e\,T_{p,q}^{0,0}\left(_{1,2,0,-1}^{0,1,0,0}\right)$$

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} Γ(n,n)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty Γ(-n-1,-n-1)= T_{p,q}^{0,0}\left(_{-1,-1,-1,-1}^{\quad 0,1,0,0}\right) $$

I already know about the [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula), but it offers no new insights. There are other [theorems](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2) that could possibly be used. How can the integral representations for the goal sum be found? If the integral representation is indeed impossible, then what is an integral  representation for a special case? This will help us solve similar problems. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: Did you just randomly spotted the $T$ function? Or is the a motivation?

Comment: @RounakSarkar As said in the bounty and question, it is a function that I made up just to show how each example is a special case of the general case. It is a motivation. Do you know how to possibly put it in an integral form?

Comment: Nah bro. I am not intelligent enough. But looking at YOUR question history, it seems that you'll find out what you want very quickly.

Comment: @RounakSarkar What do you mean by “you’ll find out what you want very quickly”? This website is just a hobby. Thanks for the support.

Comment: @RounakSarkar One last thing, there seems to have been an upvote from you associated with [this inverse gamma integral question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146975/how-can-you-simplify-verify-this-solution-for-int-0-25991-q-1x-x-xdx/4239642#4239642). I have checked part of the expansion and it works. Can you please check if the rest works? Thanks.

Comment: Wait how did you figure out that I upvoted that answer? And by the way can you answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4241711/831748) of mine?

Comment: One last thing. If I want to try to find the integral representation of the $T$ function, how do I start? I mean how does someone find an integral representation?

Comment: @RounakSarkar If the result is correct and while ignoring conditions for now, $$\int (cx)^{ax^b}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-a)^n Q(n+1,-(bn+1)\ln(cx))}{c^{bn+1}(bn+1)^{n+1}}= \frac{1}{-ac^{b-1}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ (-ac^bbn-ac^b)^{n+1}Γ(n+1,-bn\ln(cx)-\ln(cx))}{Γ(n+1,0)} =  -\frac{1}{ac^{b-1}}  T_{-abc^b,-ac^b}^{1,1}\left(_{\ \ 1,1,0,0}^{1,1,-b\ln(cx),-\ln(cx)}\right) $$ already is an integral representation. Just start with an integrand and experiment and you might find a more general answer.. Thanks again. If you cannot find a general solution then try a special case of the general.Thanks

Comment: You're right. I still have some time for getting +50 reputation. I don't think I can do it, but goddammit let me just try.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Go ahead, just do not stress too much about it. You also have the whole internet to your disposal. Thanks.

Comment: I just realized that for the second expression in your bounty, basically $T_{p,q}^{r,s}\left(_{\ \ a,b,0,0}^{A,B,C,D}\right)$ can be easily written as a double integral. You can use the definition of the incomplete gamma function to write $\Gamma(An+B,Cn+D)$ or you can just use $\Gamma(s,x)=x^s\operatorname{E}_{1-s}(x)$ and then use the definition of the generalized exponential integral. And for the bottom $\Gamma(an+b)$ we can just treat it as the [reciprocal gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_gamma_function) and use the integral definition of it.

Comment: @RounakSarkar That is a nice idea, but how about the $(pn+q)^{rn+s}$ part? I see you are doing a special case, but is there an integral representation for $\frac{1}{Γ(an+b,cn+d)}$, the denominator of the main sum?

Comment: I think you don't need to worry about $(pn+q)^{rn+s}$ because that is not really a trouble maker. And for the general case for $\frac{1}{an+b,cn+d}$, I don't know. I don't think it would be easy to derive an integral representation of it. Should I write an answer about the special case? I know that it is not really that interesting because I just plugged in a few identities in the definition of the $T$ function, but i think it can still be considered an integral representation.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Notice how I only used this special case for the integrals. I was thinking I could sneak in another case for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218525/evaluating-sum-limits-x-2-infty-frac1x), but you can totally just do the special case. Please try to write the sum in terms of integrals only and no summations. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129525/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-rounak-sarkar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a very general solution. Notice we can answer any question like this one by:

$$\int f(x) dx=g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(x)\implies f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty g’_n(x) =g(x)$$

However, we need to find g(x) in closed form. I could do the general summation in the question by finding a general solution family, but it is more beautiful when we use the special case which can be simplified using a function.

This function will be the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mittag-LefflerFunction.html):

$$\mathrm E_{a,b}(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{y^n}{Γ(an+b)}$$

Now let’s solve for $y=y(x)$ by making a simple integral equation. Let’s also make each constant a function of x, so $p=p(x),q=q(x),r=r(x),s=s(x),A=A(x),B=B(x),C=C(x),D=D(x)$

$$\int E_{a,b}(y(x))dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int \frac{y^n(x)}{Γ(an+b)}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(pn+q)^{rn+s}Γ(An+B,Cn+D)}{Γ(an+b)}$$

I could take the nth root, but the index must stay with the summation.

After playing around with more generalized y(x), a solution was found, but two of the arguments must be 1 unfortunately unless you can find a better solution. The integration can be found using gamma identities, but I had machine help:

$$\int \mathrm E_{a,b}\left(\ln^t(ux)x^v\right)dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{Γ(an+b)}dx\int \ln^{tn}(ux)x^{vn} dx=C+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n v} (u x)^{-n v} \ln^{n t}(u x) (-(n v + 1) \ln(u x))^{-n t} Γ(n t + 1, -(n v + 1) \ln(u x)) }{Γ(an+b) (n u v + u)}\quad\mathop=^{\ln^{n t}(u x)  \ln^{-n t}(u x)=1}_{x^{nv}x^{-nv}=1}\quad C+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{nt} Γ(tn  + 1, -(n v + 1) \ln(u x)) }{Γ(an+b) (n v + 1)^{tn+1} u^{vn+1}} = C+\frac1u\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-u^{\frac vt}vn  - u^{\frac vt}\right)^{-tn} Γ(tn  + 1, -v\ln(u x) n  -\ln(u x))) }{Γ(an+b) (n v + 1)}  $$

This expansion has a factor of $(nv+1)$ in the denominator which makes it difficult to put into my “T function form”. Here is a better result using the [Productlog/W-Lambert function](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ProductLog/) which also uses a bit of software help:

$$\int \mathrm E_{a,b}\left(\mathrm W^{t}(ux)x^v\right)dx=\int\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mathrm W^{tn}(ux)x^{un}}{Γ(a,b)}dx=C+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left[x^{n v} \mathrm W(u x)^{n t} e^{-n v \mathrm W(u x)} (-(n v + 1) \mathrm W(u x))^{-n (t + v)} ((n v + 1) Γ(n (t + v) + 1, -(n v + 1) \mathrm W(u x)) - Γ(n (t + v) + 2, -(n v + 1) \mathrm W(u x)))\right]}{u (n v + 1)^2 Γ(an+b)}$$

If terms can be cancelled out then, the following holds also using Lambert-W function properties:

$$\int \mathrm E_{a,b}\left(\mathrm W^{t}(ux)x^v\right)dx=C+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left[-u^{-vn-1} (-(n v + 1))^{-n (t + v)-1} Γ(n (t + v) + 1, -(n v + 1) \mathrm W(u x)) -u^{-vn-1}(-(n v + 1))^{-n(t+v)-2} Γ(n (t + v) + 2, -(n v + 1) \mathrm W(u x))]\right]}{Γ(an+b)} = C-u^{-\frac{t}{t+v}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-u^{\frac{v}{t+v}}  n v - u^{\frac{v}{t+v}} \right)^{-n (t + v)-1} Γ(n (t + v) + 1, -n v \mathrm W(u x) -\mathrm W(u x)))}{Γ(an+b)}- u^{\frac{v-t}{t+v}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\left(-u^{\frac{v}{t+v}}  n v - u^{\frac{v}{t+v}} \right)^{-n (t + v)-1} Γ(n (t + v) + 2, -n v \mathrm W(u x) -\mathrm W(u x)))}{Γ(an+b)} $$

So we mainly found an integral representation for:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(pn+q)^{rn+\{-1,0,1,2\}}Γ(An+\{1,2\},Bn+C)}{Γ(an+b)}$$

where $\{x_1,x_2,…x_i\}$ represents solved cases of a variable. If you can find a more general solution, then please let me know. Note that the [Generalized Exponential Integral function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html) simplifies the problem, but that is not the focus of the problem. Please correct me and give me feedback!

I actually  wanted a closed form for this sum and I found an analogous function called the [**Incomplete Fox-Wright functions**](https://advancesindifferenceequations.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13662-020-03067-0) where the subscripted variable are constants with respect to $n$. The bolded link has more identities. Also note the [Lower Gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html):

$$\,_pΨ_q^{(\gamma)}\left[\,^{(a_1,A_1,x),(a_2,A_2),…(a_p,A_p)}_{\quad(b_1,B_1),…,(b_p,B_p)}\ t\right]+ \,_pΨ_q^{(\Gamma)}\left[\,^{(a_1,A_1,x),(a_2,A_2),…(a_p,A_p)}_{\quad(b_1,B_1),…,(b_p,B_p)}\ t\right]\mathop=^\text{def}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(a_1+A_1n,x)\prod\limits_{j=2}^pΓ(a_j+A_jn)t^n}{\prod\limits_{j=2}^p \Gamma(b_j+B_jn)n!}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{γ(a_1+A_1n,x)\prod\limits_{j=2}^pΓ(a_j+A_jn)t^n}{\prod\limits_{j=2}^p \Gamma(b_j+B_jn)n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\prod\limits_{j=1}^pΓ(a_j+A_jn)t^n}{\prod\limits_{j=2}^p \Gamma(b_j+B_jn)n!} = \,_pΨ_q\left[\,^{(a_1,A_1,x),(a_2,A_2),…(a_p,A_p)}_{\quad(b_1,B_1),…,(b_p,B_p)}\ t\right] $$

Which is the [**Fox-Wright function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) inspired from [@Harry Peter’s post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961113/how-are-fox-h-functions-useful-in-math) and Therefore:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(A+Bn,C)t^n\Gamma(1n+1)}{\Gamma(аn+b)n!}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(A+Bn,C)t^n}{\Gamma(а+bn)} =\,_2Ψ^{(\Gamma)}_1\left[\,^{(A,B,C),(1,1)}_{\quad(a,b)}\ t\right]$$

which is still not enough to solve general tetration type integrals, but works for some problems. Maybe I will post some later. This function seem like an excuse for any similar sum, but still can be simplified into a few simpler function.

Comment: I knew that you would find a way to get an answer. Remember my second comment in the question.

Comment: @RounakSarkar note that “c=d=0” and “B=s=1”, but it should work for most problems as usually “tetration type” integrals have these properties. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. You are getting closer.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this function? By the way, did you name the function $T$ because your user name starts with $T$?

Comment: @RounakSarkar No, I named it for “tetration” becuase of the title. Let me see the progress…

Comment: I also found that most $$\sum_a^\infty A_n=\int_a^\infty \lfloor x\pm 1\rfloor \frac{d}{dx} A_x dx$$ as seen with [John Barber’s method in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255028/how-to-evaluate-sum-limits-x-0-infty-texterfcx-1-16199904794712636353). An application for a special case of the “made up T” function is [**here under the “another integral representation” section**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4218525/evaluating-sum-limits-x-2-infty-frac1x-in-exact-form). Have you made any progress on finding $\mathcal R$?. Is it short for “radius” or “Rounak”?

Comment: I think my interest has been shifted from $\mathcal{R}$ to some other stuff, so I haven't really made any progress, but don't worry I will work on it in a while.