# Is there a general way to find an integral representation of a function?

Tags: integration, functions, representation-theory

### $\underline{\text{Motivation}:-}$

This question really came to my mind when I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4232284/831748) question where OP is asking for the integral representation of a function he created. This got me thinking, are there general ways to represent functions as integrals?

### $\underline{\text{My Question}:-}$

My question is really simple-

**Is there a general way to find out the integral representations of a function?**

**Or do we just keep finding identities involving the function until we just happen to find one involving integrals**?

You can clarify using some examples.

I already know about the [Abel-plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula).

**Edit:**

For example we can write the zeta function as this

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{1}{2}+2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(s\tan^{-1}(t)}{(1+t^2)^\frac{s}{2}(e^{2\pi t}-1)}dt}$

Basically what I mean by integral representation of some function $f(x)$ is-

$\textstyle\displaystyle{f(x)=g(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}h(x,t)dt}$

Here, $f(x), g(x), a(x), b(x)$ and $h(x,t)$ are all continuous functions.

I don't want obvious answers like-

$g=f$ and $a=b$

Or $g=0$ and $b(x)=x$ and $a(x)=\rho$ such that $f(\rho)=0$ and $h(x,t)=f'(t)$. You can just put these in the equation and realize that this is just FTC.

You can just feel it with your heart that these are not interesting answers. I basically want interesting answers, for example the Abel-plana formula is an interesting one, but since I already know it, there is no reason to repeat.

To be honest I don't know how to clarify more than just saying I want an interesting answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "integral representation"? Maybe clarify with an example?

Comment: @Arthur. OK let me put some examples.

Comment: What kind of conditions do you have on $g$ and $h$? I'm assuming taking $g=f$ and $h=0$ is not a good answer...

Comment: @Stefan Lafon. I have edited the question, please read it again.

Comment: Answer:  No, there is no general way to do this.

Comment: @GEdgar. This is possibly the most general answer I have ever seen.

Comment: See [Riemann sums](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum), [Darboux’s formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_formula), and [Euler Maclaurin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula) formula. There are many similar formulas, but they would need the series representation of a function and certain conditions depending on the summation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a versatile formula that I learned from:

> [How to evaluate $$\sum\limits_{x=0}^\infty \text{erfc}(x)= 1.1619990479471263635323…?$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255028/how-to-evaluate-sum-limits-x-0-infty-texterfcx-1-16199904794712636353)

where the answer from @StevenClark was good, but the most creative answer was from @John Barber with one solution as the following:

> In this sum of integrals, the interval $[0,1)$ will be counted only once, in the $n = 0$ term. The interval $[1,2)$ will be counted twice, in the $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ terms. And so on. This means we can write:
> $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{erfc}(n) \;=\;
> \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}\, \lfloor t+1\rfloor \,e^{-t^2}\, dt+1+\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_1^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor e^{-x^2} dx$$

Therefore a general formula for an integral representation for a function defined by a sum which works for many functions:

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty f(x)=\int_0^\infty \lfloor x-a\rfloor df(x)=\int_0^\infty \lfloor x-a\rfloor f’(x) dx\implies \int_0^\infty \lfloor x-a\rfloor f(x)dx=\sum_{x=0}^\infty\int f(x)dx\mathop=^{\int f(x)dx=F(x)}\sum_{x=0}^\infty F(x)$$

where every situation that I ever used this formula had $a\in\{-1,0,1\}$

Here is another example using the [Modified Bessel Function of the Second Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) and [Kelvin functions $\text{kei}(x),\text{ker}(x)$](https://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/) with [this computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+%E2%88%AB+floor%28x%29+%28-1%29%5E%281%2F4%29+%28kelvinkei%281%2Cx%29+-+i+kelvinker%281%2Cx%29%29+from+1+to+100)

$$\sum_\Bbb N(\text{ker(x)}+ i\text{kei}(x))=\sum_\Bbb N \text K_0\left(\sqrt i x\right) =\sqrt[4]{-1}\int_0^\infty\lfloor x\rfloor \text{kei}_1(x)dx+\sqrt[-4]{-1}\int_1^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor \text{ker}_1(x)dx=(-1)^{-\frac34}\int_1^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor \text K_1\left(\sqrt[4]{-1} x\right)dx= 0.133691752819604391549325780771600891… - 0.725631207729182631737443031218031025… i $$

which has a more traditional integral representation in the [**question**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253802/evaluation-of-sum-limits-bbb-n-text-kerxi-textkeix-sum-limits), but that does not use this floor function method. I will add more new examples later. You can also put it in terms of other functions using [**these floor function identities**](https://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/Floor/27/). This method does not work if the derivative of $f(x)$ has a term canceled. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: This is good enough.

Comment: @RounakSarkar Evaluation of the integral in floor function form will probably just bring you back to the sum form. Thanks for the accept.